# openxml bulk find and replace words in a template dotx

Tags: replace, openxml

Im trying to replace "" in a word template using openXML

```
            foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("/descendant::w:t", nsManager))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(node.InnerText);
            }
```

The above doesnt work, I'm getting broken down parts of the text, e.g. "<" and "sometag" and then ">".

I want to replace the full text

```
      "<sometag>"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This blog talks about Search Replace functionality. [Link](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2011/05/12/148357.aspx)
You can understand the Algorithm or just take sample code and use it. You will need to install [Open Xml SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) to use sample code.